# Listing all the users with home folder size in MB in Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have to list all the users with their home folder size in MB and save it in a file. Now, I do know how to list all the users that is by,

cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1

and also how to list the home folder size of a particular user, i.e. by:

du -sch /home/Username/*

but how to do combine the two, I have no clue on. Also, I have to list the file size in mbs.

Comment: Don't cat and pipe into something that takes files as input.

Comment: `man du` provides the option for listing the file size in MB.

Comment: `cut` can take a file parameter, why use `cat`?  `cut -d -f1 /etc/passwd`

Comment: Ok I save it in a file then what to do? @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ How to loop through all users?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
for user in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd); do
    if [ -d /home/$user ]; then
       du -sh -BM /home/$user
    fi
done
```